# How to write handles for classes that don't have clone() member?

Tags: c++, clone

I'm following an example in *Accelerated C++* and writing a simple `Handle` class that will act as a smart pointer. This uses the [virtual ctor idiom](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.8) using a virtual `clone()` function. So far so good. But what to do when I want to use my `Handle` for classes that I don't control that don't provide `clone()`?

The method suggested in the book is to create a global `clone` function and use **template specialization** (something I'm seeing for the first time) so that if `clone()` is called with a particular argument, one can write code to handle that case.

**My question is**: This means that I have to write a `clone()` version for *every* type of class that I envision my user can use `Handle` with. This seems quite hard! Is there a more elegant and/or simple way to solve this issue? How is it possible that things like auto_ptr or boost::shared_ptr are able to provide this functionality without the tedious `clone()` definitions?

For completeness, here's my `Handle` class implementation:

```
template <class T> class Handle
{
public:
    Handle() : p(0) {}
    Handle(T* t) : p(t) {}
    Handle( const Handle& s ) :p(0) { if (s.p) p = s.p->clone(); }
    const Handle& operator=( const Handle& );
    ~Handle() { delete p; }

    operator bool() { return p; }

    T& operator*() { if (p) return *p; else throw std::runtime_error("Handle not bound"); }
    T* operator->() { if (p) return p; else throw std::runtime_error("Handle not bound"); }
private:
    T* p; 
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Using clone() is not very C++ like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to simply not write `Handle`s for these kinds of classes. No. Really.

`auto_ptr` (deprecated as of C++11) never needs to clone the underlying object, because `auto_ptr` never copies the object. An `auto_ptr` only ever has one copy of the object, and when the `auto_ptr` is copied, control of the object is transfered -- that object is not copied.

`unique_ptr` never needs to clone the underlying object, because there is only ever one `unique_ptr` that owns the object. `unique_ptr` is noncopyable, and is only movable.

`shared_ptr` never needs to clone because it also only ever controls one copy of the object. Copying the `shared_ptr` only increments the reference count, and that single object is destroyed when the reference count is zero.

In general, if there's no way to deep copy the resource your class is controlling, then you should just make the class noncopyable. If clients need to pass references to your class around, they can place the class in an `auto_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, or `shared_ptr` themselves.